# How to create Dll for VS08 which were made earliar in VS06

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, windows-ce

I Have a DLL which is made in vs6. Now I want to create that Dll in VS2008. So that all the functionality remains same.

Comment: VS2006? Do you mean VS2005? Have you tried just opening the project in VS2008?

Comment: So what's the problem? Compile it in VS2008.

Comment: Yes,I tried.but popup window show that this project can not be open in this platform

Comment: Actully I have to create a dll that's functionality will be same as previus dll.

Comment: Could it be that you DLL is for Windows CE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too terrible, though the fact you're coming from VS 6 tells me it's a desktop DLL that you're trying to build for CE.

The first steps are easy:

1. Install an SDK for your target processor architecture.
2. Create a brand-new Project (don't try upgrading the existing)
3. Add the existing header and code files to the project
4. Compile

The next step is to fix whatever errors you get, but we have no idea what you'll hit.  Maybe the code is using ASCII Win32 calls that are not supported in CE> Moving to the wide-character versions is pretty easy.  Maybe it's using APIs that simply don't exist in CE.  In that case, it's going to be much harder to port.  Only you will know because only you have the code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your VS2008 doesn't support Windows CE platform. You need to add it to VS2008. And a platform name in VS2008 should match to the platform name in VS6. Otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: Yes,It open now and I compile it,various errors are there like "fatal error c1017".

Comment: Check preprocessor definition in a new project settings. Sometimes MSVS converts them wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean Visual Studio 6, right?

If yes, then try opening the vcproj file(or your workspace file having extension .dsw) with VS2008. A Migration wizard will pop up. Migrate the project and then come back and post the problems you face while building the project with VS2008.

Comment: ,there is a file with extention vcw.and when I click on it,popup window is open and the message is "to open it,please use the version that support this type of project".